# Error while running code - makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I'm trying to run my code but I get 5 errors and they're all of the same kind.
The first is:

> note: expected 'int (*)[3]' but argument is of type 'int'

In, for example, this part of my code (it points out on the line where you see the word HERE

```
HERE-> int isNeighbourClose(int mat[N][M], int i, int j, int a, int b){

     int m;

     m=calcDistance(mat[i][j], mat[a][b]);
     if(m<=1)
     {
         return 1;
     }
     return 0;
   }
```

And the other is:

> error: passing argument 1 of 'isNeighbourClose' makes pointer from integer without a cast

In, for example, this part of my code

```
int isCellExtreme(int mat[N][M], int i, int j){

    int a, b;
    int m;

    for(a=-1;a<=1;a++)
    {
        if((i+a>=0) && (i+a<=N))
        {
            for(b=-1;b<=1;b++)
            {
                if((j+b>=0) && (j+b<=M))
                {
                    if((a!=0)||(b!=0))
                    {
          HERE->          m=isNeighbourClose(mat[N][M], i, j, i+a, j+b);
                        if(m)
                        {
                            return 0; 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I went over this a couple of times and can't find where the problem is. Any idea where I'm mistaken?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a function prototype for that function floating around somewhere?

Comment: Hi. Which of the two functions are you talking about?

Comment: change the call in `isCellExtreme` to `m=isNeighbourClose(mat, i, j, i+a, j+b);` and see if that works better.

Comment: Thank you. It works now. Can you please explain what I did wrong with calling mat[N][M]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass `mat[N][M]` to `isNeighbourClose`, you're not passing a 2D array like you think you are.  You're passing in the single element of `mat` at row `N` column `M`.

The function expects a 2D array, so pass the whole array:

```
m=isNeighbourClose(mat, i, j, i+a, j+b);
```

EDIT:

When you have a **declaration** like this:

```
int mat[N][M];
```

You're specifying the datatype and (in this case) the dimensions of the array, i.e. it says "mat is an array of N by M elements".  This differs from an **expression** as mentioned above where `mat` is being used.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!

Comment: Wait. So when do I declare mat[N][M] and when do I omit the [N][M]?

Comment: Got it. Thank you dbush!

Comment: @FlyGuy Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.